# Firebase won't initialize, unless I refresh the page

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app using Ionic, Angular and Firebase.

Whenever I try to access a specific Tab right after logging in, I get
this error message:

[image]

However, once I refresh the Page the error message disappears and I can access the tab.

What I want is to access the tab without having to refresh the page.

My Tab3.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import "@ionic/angular";
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login.page';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);

firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})

export class Tab3Page implements OnInit {

  uid;
  email;
  username;
  dp;
  users = [];

  constructor(public nav: NavController) {
    this.uid = localStorage.getItem("uid");
    firebase.firestore().collection("chatUsers").doc(this.uid).get().then(userData => {
      this.username = userData.data()['username'];
      this.email = userData.data()['email'];
      this.dp = userData.data()['dp'];
    }); console.log(this.uid);
    firebase.firestore().collection("chatUsers").get().then(userData => {
      userData.forEach(childData => {
        if (childData.data()['uid'] != this.uid) {
          this.users.push(childData.data());
        }
      })
    });
  }

  gotochat(uid, username, email) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("uid", uid);
    sessionStorage.setItem("username", username);
    this.nav.navigateForward("/chat");
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

I don't know if you need this as well but here is my login.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  email: string;
  pwd: string;

  constructor(public fs: AngularFirestore, public af: AngularFireAuth, public nav: NavController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
    this.af.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.pwd).then((userData) => {
      this.nav.navigateRoot('/tabs')
      localStorage.setItem("uid",userData.user.uid)
    }).catch(err => {
      alert(err.message)
    })
  }

  goto_signup() {
    this.nav.navigateForward('/signup')
  }

}
```

I'm still new to Ionic, so I don't really know how I could resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post also your routes? Anyway, I suggest you move `firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);` and the `enablePermission` in `AppComponent`.

Comment: The firebase setup should reside in your app module- that worked for me in an ionic tab project
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [InAppBrowser, SplashScreen, StatusBar, {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by moving `firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase)` to my `app.module.ts`.

Thanks to @Shifenis for providing me with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on an Ionic tabs project. I'd recommend adding the setup for firebase in your module. Happy to share a slackblitz, if you would like.

**Code**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [InAppBrowser, SplashScreen, StatusBar, {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```